# How to use escalc function?

Tags: r, metafor

I am working on a meta analysis using the metafor package. I want to calculate the effect size in using the package but am running into some trouble. I am trying to calculate effect size using the escalc function. I have a file with values ~200 rows containing data on the control/test means variances, and sample numbers. For each row I would like to calculate the effect size. I would now like to use the escalc function to determiner the effect size using SMD.

My current code is as follows:

```
# escalc function
escalc <- function(measure, ai, bi, ci, di, n1i, n2i, x1i, x2i, t1i, t2i, m1i, m2i, sd1i, sd2i, xi, mi, ri, ti, sdi, r2i, ni, yi, vi, sei,
data, slab, subset, include, add=1/2, to="only0", drop00=FALSE, vtype="LS", var.names=c("yi","vi"), add.measure=FALSE, append=TRUE, replace=TRUE, digits, ...)

# apply data and add effect size col to data frame
data$ES <- escalc(measure = SMD, dat$MRE1, dat$MTE2, dat$VRE1, dat$VTE2, dat$NR1, dat$NR2, data = dat)
```

When I run this code once there seems to be no problem/error (if I run the code more than once it says "Error: C stack usage 15925888 is too close to the limit" - unsure what this means) but my dataframe does not have a new column with the ES for each study. When I highlight the new variable and click enter (to see what the data looks like) it says NULL so I don't think it actually ran. How can I get a summary of the effect sizes?

I am unsure what I am doing wrong or how to see what the effect sizes I've calculated are. I've been reading the metafor documentation and am unsure what I am doing wrong (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/metafor/metafor.pdf). Do I need to calculate escalc for each paper? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
dat <- escalc(measure="SMD", m1i=MRE1, m2i=MTE2, sd1i=sqrt(VRE1), sd2i=sqrt(VTE2), n1i=NR1, n2i=NR2, data=dat)
```

Note that the SDs are the input for arguments `sd1i` and `sd2i`, so if you have the variances, we need to take the square-root of them.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I did try this but I keep getting this error:  "Error: C stack usage  15924448 is too close to the limit". Do you know how to increase the stack usage?

Comment: Works perfectly fine here. An example: `dat <- data.frame(MRE1=c(1,1), MTE2=c(1,1), VRE1=c(1,1), VTE2=c(1,1), NR1=c(10,10), NR2=c(2,2)); dat <- escalc(measure="SMD", m1i=MRE1, m2i=MTE2, sd1i=sqrt(VRE1), sd2i=sqrt(VTE2), n1i=NR1, n2i=NR2, data=dat)` Please provide a fully reproducible example. Also, if your code actually contains `escalc <- function(...)`, then this makes no sense (you are overwriting the escalc function).

Comment: Thank you for the help! I was able to calculate the effect size! I'm not sure if you know how to do this, but do you know how to make the effect size variance show up in the data frame? It must have been calculated and should be in the new data frame I made as the number of variables in it increased from 49 to 51, when I click to view the data frame I can see the effect sizes, but I cannot see the variances calculated. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Sounds like you are using RStudio. When you view the data (using the spreadsheet view), it shows the first 50 variables. Next to '0-50' you will see '> >>' - click on that, then you can see the rest.